# Limit the number of child pages

Tags: php, query-posts

I have this html structure:

```
<home>
<Web>
   <web 1>
   <web 2>
   <web 3>
   <web 4>
   <web 5>
   <web 6>
   <web 7>
 </web>
<Print>
   <Print 1>
   <Print 2>
   <Print 3>
   <Print 4>
   <Print 5>
</print>
<Art>
   <Art 1>
   <Art 2>
   <Art 3>
   <Art 4>
   <Art 5>
   <Art 6>
</art>
</home>
```

I use this to display the grandchildrens content while hiding its parent

```
<?php $counter = 1 ?>
<div class="row-fluid">

<?php 
if ( have_posts() ) {
while ( have_posts() ) {
    the_post();

    $args=array(
            'orderby' => 'menu_order',
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post__not_in' => array(4,368,358,354),
            'post_type' => 'page',
            'post__in' => $pageIDs
    );

    $childpages = new WP_Query($args);

    if($childpages->post_count > 0) { /* display the children content  */
        while ($childpages->have_posts()) {
             $childpages->the_post(); ?>
    <div class="span4">
                <?php 
            echo "<h2>".get_the_title()."</h2>";
                    echo the_content(); 
        ?>
    </div>
    <? if ($counter % 3 == 0): ?>
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php $counter++; ?>

       <?php }
    }
    wp_reset_query();
}
}

?>
</div>
```

At the moment all grandchildrens are displayed, how do I limit the number of grandchildrens to be 3 per type (3 for the print, 3 for the web and 3 for the art)?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I solved it:

```
<?php
 /*
  Template Name: home
  */
  get_header(); ?>

 <?php $counter = 1 ?>
 <div class="row-fluid"> 
 <?php
$args = array(
 'child_of' => 4,
 'parent' => 0,
 'post_type' => 'page',
 'post_status' => 'publish'
); 
 $childrens =   query_posts('showposts=3&post_parent=4&post_type=page&orderby=menu_order&order=DESC');

  foreach ( $childrens as $children ) :
 query_posts('showposts=3&post_parent='.$children->ID.'&post_type=page&orderby=menu_order&order=DESC');
if ( have_posts ) :
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
 ?>
    <div class="span4">
        <h2>
            <?php the_title(); ?>
        </h2>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>
  <? if ($counter % 3 == 0): ?>
 <div id="content" class="row-fluid"></div>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid">
   <?php endif; ?>
    <?php $counter++; ?>
<?php
endwhile;
 endif;
endforeach;
?>
 </div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```